# Can I fix Conceal highlight group background in highlighted lines?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

In VIM I'm using syntastic configured to highlight the lines with warnings and errors:

[image: haskell code]

The problem is the background of concealed characters. As can be seen, `λ`, which replaces `\`, gets a different background than the line highlighted (it's not my cursor there). Notice that `ctermbg=NONE` for the `Conceal` highlighting group.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this, too, and I don't think there's a way to overcome this. The priorities of syntax highlighting, `'hlsearch'`, `'cursorline'`, and concealed characters (which is a part of syntax highlighting) are fixed and cannot be overruled. You can only influence the priority of the `matchadd()` definitions.

Comment: There are many open ends with regards to concealing, unfortunately. The conceals aren't printed (`:hardcopy`), neither. Patches and volunteers would be very welcome, but I understand that Vim's source code isn't exactly inviting to newcomers...

Answer (score 1):

`:hi clear Conceal` to turn off the conceal highlight.
[I found it here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/lqshgf/turn_off_highlighting_in_vimtex_tex_conceal_option/)